# Error when trying to make an object

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

I'm trying to make a `Question` object. `Question` being the class but I'm getting an error which is:

> Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from `Questions *` to `Questions`

I'm trying to make an object so I could put it into a `multimap` of type `<int, Questions>`

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Questions.h"
using namespace std;

Questions::Questions() {}
Questions::Questions(string question,string correctAnswer, string wrongAnswer1,string wrongAnswer2,string wrongAnswer3) {}

void Questions::questionStore() {
    Questions q1 = new Questions("Whats the oldest known city in the world?", "Sparta", "Tripoli", "Rome", "Demascus");
    string q2 = ("What sport in the olympics are beards dissallowed?", "Judo", "Table Tennis", "Volleyball", "Boxing");
    string q3 = ("What does an entomologist study?", "People", "Rocks", "Plants", "Insects");
    string q4 = ("Where would a cowboy wear his chaps?", "Hat", "Feet", "Arms", "Legs");
    string q5 = ("which of these zodiac signs is represented as an animal that does not grow horns?", "Aries", "Tauris", "Capricorn", "Aquarius");
    string q6 = ("Former Prime Minister Tony Blair was born in which country?", "Northern Ireland", "Wales", "England", "Scotland");
    string q7 = ("Duffle coats are named after a town in which country?", "Austria", "Holland", "Germany", "Belgium");
    string q8 = ("The young of which creature is known as a squab?", "Horse", "Squid", "Octopus", "Pigeon");
    string q9 = ("The main character in the 2000 movie ""Gladiator"" fights what animal in the arena?", "Panther", "Leopard", "Lion", "Tiger");

    map.insert(pair <int, Questions>(1, q1));
    map.insert(pair <int, string>(2, q2));
    // map.insert(pair<int,string>(3, q3));
    for (multimap <int, string, std::less <int> >::const_iterator iter = map.begin(); iter != map.end(); ++iter)
        cout << iter->first << '\t' << iter->second << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `q1` should be a pointer declare it this way `Questions *q1`.

Comment: All of your strings are going to be the rightmost value. Also, if you need a pointer, please don't use `new`. Use a smart pointer instead.

Comment: The way you're using double quotes in the q9 string is wrong. Replace `""Gladiator""` with `\"Gladiator\"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Questions q1 = new Questions` is incorrect syntax.

From  `map.insert(pair <int, Questions>(1, q1));` I can see your `map` value type is Questions object instead of Questions pointer, so it should be

```
Questions q1 = Questions ("Whats the oldest known city in the world?", "Sparta" , "Tripoli" , "Rome", "Demascus");
```

Also your variable map is having the same name as std::map which is a STL container, suggest you use another name, for example: `question_map`;

**Edit**

To allow `<< iter->second` you need to overload `operator<<` for Questions type.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(const std::ostream& out, const Questions& q)
{
    out << q.question;  // I made up this member as I can't see your Questions code
    return out;
}
```

Comment: When i change to that can you see a problem with this line cout << iter->first << '\t' << iter->second << '\n';

Comment: Im getting this error: Error 1 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Questions' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Actually that's another issue. it's related to ` << iter->second` but you haven't overload operator<< for Questions type yet.

Comment: I know im a noob but how would i do that?

Comment: I declared it in the header and it says i have too many parameters.

Comment: put it as non-member function.

Comment: I dont know what a non-member function is :(

Comment: put it out side Questions class :D

Comment: Im still getting the same errors.  Would you mind taking a look on team viewer ?

Comment: Sorry mate, that's too far. May I suggest you search on SO for function overloading, you can find heaps of them.

Comment: Np yeah ive been googling but cant understand itr

Answer (score 1):

The `new` expression gives you a pointer to the object you've dynamically allocated. You need to do `Questions* q1 = new Questions(...);`. But if you don't need to dynamically allocate (you end up copying the object into your map) don't bother. Just do `Questions q1(...);`.

Presumably you will change the following lines (`q2`, `q3`, etc.) to match, but as they are they are not doing what you expect. The `(..., ..., ...)` will evaluate to be the right-most item in this comma-separated list. So your `q2` line is equivalent to `string q2 = "Boxing";`.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your `questionScore` method is the problem:

```
Questions q1 = new Questions ...
```

`new x` returns a pointer to an `x` object, therefore `q1` should be defined as a pointer.

```
Questions * q1 = new Questions ...
```